# Java array after loop

Tags: java, arrays

can you explain to me how  `a[i] = a[a[i]]` works?

```
int[] a = new int[10]
for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    a[i] = 9 - i

for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
    a[i] = a[a[i]]

for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: It works the same way as  `a[i]`

Comment: `int temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[temp];`. `a[i]` is an `int`, you can look up an element of `a` by index using an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the first `for loop` complete its execution
this how a array looks like

```
a[0]|a[1]|a[2]|a[3]|a[4]|a[5]|a[6]|a[7]|a[8]|a[9]
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    
 9  | 8  |  7 |  6 |  5 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 | 0
________________________________________________
```

... and after the Second for loop complete its execution
this how array looks like

```
a[0]|a[1]|a[2]|a[3]|a[4]|a[5]|a[6]|a[7]|a[8]|a[9]
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    
 0  | 1  |  2 |  3 |  4 |  4 |  3 | 2  |  1 | 0
```

**UPDATE**

after a quick look `a[i]=i` is the same as `a[i]=[a[i]]` but it doesn't
...the first four element in `a array` in the second loop will change by the last four element in old `a array`,  so since we have changed the first four element in `a array` the last four will be the same as first but in backward

Comment: *eventually a[i]=a[a[i]] is the same as a[i]=i* - No, `a[i]=a[a[i]]` will be the same as `a[i] = a[9 - i]`. *and after the Second for loop complete its execution this how array looks like* - No. It won't look like that. Please try before giving wrong answers.

Comment: thank you   @BackSlash ihave updated my answer to what you said